# Чтение из файла BufferedReader

Tags: java, файлы

По сути у меня есть метод, который считывает слова из файла и записывает в массив. Пример текстового файла:

www mail login password
www1 mail1 login1 password1

но я хочу понимать, какие слова на новой строке, а какие нет, подскажите как это сделать, сейчас мой код выглядит так.

```
BufferedReader fileReader;
        String buf[] = new String[0];

        {
            try {
                String str = null;
                fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\...\\src\\model\\file.txt"));
                while ((str = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //получаем новые слова
                    String[] newWords = str.split(" ");
                    //создаем расширенный массив
                    String[] result = new String[buf.length + newWords.length];
                    //копируем элементы в массив
                    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, result, 0, buf.length);
                    System.arraycopy(newWords, 0, result, buf.length, newWords.length);
                    //присваиваем результирующий массив текущему
                    buf = result;
                }
                fileReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы использовал обычный file и Scanner, если вам нужно просто считать строки из текстового файла и вывести их в консоль. Примерно так:

```
  package com.company;

  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;

  public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Ниже путь к файлу
    File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\Schitka\\src\\com\\company\\Test.txt");

    // Связываем объект Scanner с нашим файлом
    Scanner scanf = new Scanner(myFile);
    String temp ="";
    // Пока в файле есть строки
    while (scanf.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(scanf.nextLine()); // или temp=scanf.nextLine();

        // temp можно разбить по разделителям и заполнить словами массив или сразу использовать temp для чего-либо.
    }
    scanf.close();

   }
  }
```

Если нужно считать русские слова из файла, откройте файл в бинарном режиме, а после того, как поработайте с ним — закройте с помощью метода

```
  .close();
```

Если нужно считать каждый символ в строке

```
      FileReader fileOut = null;
      try {
        fileIn = new FileReader("Test.txt");
        int a;
        while((a = fileIn.read()) != -1) {
            fileOut.write(a);
        }
    } finally {
        if (fileIn != null) {
            fileIn.close();
        }
```